# Can a file be private but still visible to anyone with the exact URL?

Tags: bitbucket

I have a source file on bitbucket that I don't want searchable but that I do want visitable if someone enters the exact URL. YouTube has this for videos and it's useful because I can send a link of a private video to a few friends who don't need YouTube accounts to view the video but I know no one without the URL can find it. Is this possible with BitBucket? I don't want the people I want to send the URL to to have to set up a bitbucket account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently [Bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org) does not offer the feature you are asking for. You can keep your file either completely private(only allowed users can access the file) or completely public(anyone can access the file).